# C:\users\NeganPc >can react project1 The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: save, npm-install, mkdir, cd, npm-init

C:\users\ neganpc<can react project1 the system cannot find the path specified

I was installing react js app but it shows me that how can I install react js using nodejs because I am stack from there. Below are the steps I have been trying to install react but it shows me that error